# Many else and if statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I am reading a csv file which has column names in first line and values in line >1. I need to get the position of the column name. The only way I can think of is to do either switch or ifs. I read it somewhere that in my case , it is faster (better) to do the ifs. However the file has many columns (~120). Just wondering if there is an alternative(s).

```
private static void Get_Position(string line, performance p)
{
    string[] line_split = line.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < line_split.Length; i++)
    {
       if (line_split[i].Contains(@"(0)\% Processor Time"))
        {
            p.percore[0] = i;
        }
        else if (line_split[i].Contains(@"(1)\% Processor Time"))
        {
            p.percore[1] = i;
        }
        else if (line_split[i].Contains("Private Bytes"))
        {}
        else if (line_split[i].contains("DPC")
        {
         }

        //on and on and on with else ifs
```

Comment: By `Get_Position` do you mean the index of a particular column?

Comment: Are all lines really (_a number increasing by one_)\% Processor Time?

Comment: @AustinSalonen, yes the position of the columns. and the words to search are unique (120 of them)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault. no. I just edited the post

Answer (score 6):

What is preventing you from using a loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < line_split.Length; i++)
{
   for(var j = 0; j < 120; j++)
   {
      if(line_split[i].Contains(@"(" + j + ")\% Processor Time"))
      {
         p.percore[j] = i;
      }
   }
...
```

To maintain the same functionality as `if` `else if` then you could use a `break` inside the conditional.

Edit: The edit now made it clear that there is no clear pattern to the string in contains. Still, if you are writing out 120 if/else if statements you should store what you will be looking for in some type of collection. For example, a List would work. Then access the index `j` of the collection in your loop:

```
...
var listOfSearchItems = new List<string>() { "Private Bytes", "DPC" };

for (int i = 0; i < line_split.Length; i++)
{
   for(var j = 0; j < 120; j++)
   {
      if(line_split[i].Contains(listOfSearchItems[j])
      {
         p.percore[j] = i;
      }
   }
...
```

Comment: Looks like those `j`s should be `i`.

Comment: @Joe other way around, actually. The i in the loop conditional should be a j.

Comment: @JoeEnos Thanks, I did have an `i` swapped where a `j` should have been.

Comment: sorry wasn't too clear before. just edited. the ifs contains are varies not just Processor Time

Comment: You should really use more descriptive variable names, then you wouldn't mix them up.

Comment: @JohnRyann Just edited with what I would do in that situation.

Comment: @DanTeesdale, so I guess it's the same. we still have to do ifs 120 times except now we put it in a loop. appreciate the input though